# Como determinar se é possível escalonar processos utilizando o algoritmo EDF (Earliest Deadline First)?

Tags: algoritmo

Bom, meu professor me pediu para fazer um algoritmo **EM LINGUAGEM C** que recebe um valor **N** que é o número de processos a serem avaliados. Em seguida ele recebe **N** pares de valores, cada par em uma linha. Cada linha irá ter um valor **C** e outro valor **P**, representando o custo computacional, e o período de cada processo.

Exemplo de entrada:

```
2
3 5
2 5
```

Exemplo de Saida

```
OK
```

Para as entradas, o programa deverá imprimir **OK**, caso seja possível efetuar o escalonamento através do algoritmo EDF, ou **FAIL** caso não seja possível efetuar o escalonamento através do algoritmo EDF.

O problema é que, não estou compreendendo como funciona o algoritmo EDF.
Alguém poderia me explicar como resolver esse problema ?

Comment: Qual sua dúvida? O que você tentou? O que significa esses custos e períodos? Tem algum exemplo que possa fornecer que retorne a falha?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, dizem que se uma conjunto de tarefas com tempo de processamento e custo computacional não for escalonada pelo algoritmo **EDF** não será escalona por nenhum outro algoritmo, pois esse é o melhor que se encontra em operação até agora.

Respondendo minha própria pergunta para próximos que tiverem essa mesma duvida.

Dado um conjunto de tarefas com seus respectivos **custo computacional** e **tempo de processamento** só será possível realizar o escalonamento se, o somatório de todos os pares de **custo e tempo**, onde o somatório de **custo** dividido pelo **tempo** é <= 1.0 !!

**Lembrando que você deve retirar os pares repetidos.**